# i want to add the values which are in my realtime firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

this is realtime database where p_price is the product price i want to add to get the total price of the shopping cart

[image]

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    private ListView mProdList;

    private ArrayList<String> mProducts = new ArrayList<>();

    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Product");

        mProdList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.prod_list);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mProducts);

        mProdList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        mDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                String value = dataSnapshot.child("p_id").getValue(String.class);

                String value1 = dataSnapshot.child("p_name").getValue(String.class);

                Integer value2 = dataSnapshot.child("p_price").getValue(Integer.class);

                mProducts.add("Product ID: \n" + value);

                mProducts.add("Product Name: \n" + value1);

                mProducts.add("Product Price: \n" + value2);

                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

i want to display the total cart price and do the payment accordingly
i am using default arrayadapter.....if someone knows how to make a custom arrayadapter please help me in the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase already prepared to calculate total. You can try code below.

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Product");
//Put this code here, after the mDatabase
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
        int totalPrice = 0;
        for (DataSnapshot snapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            if (snapShot.exists()) {
                int size = snapShot.child("p_price").getValue(Integer.class);
                totalPrice += size;

            //Display total
            textViewTotal.setText(String.valueOf(totalPrice));
        }
    }
   }

   @Override
   public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

   }
});
```

You can refer to this link.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59944838/9346054

You can database for cart something like this.

```
Cart
    -userUid
        -cartUid
            -productUid
                -cartUidValue
                -dateCreated
                -productUidValue
```

Comment: i love you bro...you made my day...this was my degree project...an employee-less store....now i am getting the total cart value

Comment: dont know if i should ask this....but if you can i want to make a beautiful shopping cart which will have these three values and the image of product....can you help me

Comment: @DhruvJain you can pressed 'tick' yes button to accept this as answer. I updated the answer